# Add a CSS class based on categroy id to archive pages

Tags: plugins, php, css

How can I add a css class based on categroy id in archive pages body in wordpress?

I want to style each category page different

Comment: Hi Naderi, can you share your code for the archive pages with us? And tell us which element you want a class added to? Most likely it's very easy.

Comment: The body already gets a unique class for each category.

Comment: here is my category page :
http://bestwiki.palette-webdesign.ir/category/cinema/
and there is no unique class for this

Answer (score 0):

the link you gave has category class "category-26", so therefore to add custom styling to this specific page you just have to define class .category-26 before any of your custom style, example of adding custom css to specific your category page :

```
.category-26 article {
    background: #9999;
}
```

You can find specific category key with inspect element in `<body>` tag , in your case it was : `<body class="rtl archive category category-cinema category-26 theme-aryan woocommerce-js elementor-default expansion-alids-init">`